# simple for-loop or lapply solution needed

Tags: r, data.table

I have a set a list of factors that looks like this:

```
v.list <- c('AM','EM','SMH')
```

I would like to calculate new columns in a data set based on previous columns in the data set, that all are unqiuely defined by one of these identifiers. Here are some example data to illustrate:

```
height.pre.AM   <- rnorm(10)
height.pre.EM   <- rnorm(10)
height.pre.SMH  <- rnorm(10)
height.post.AM  <- rnorm(10)
height.post.EM  <- rnorm(10)
height.post.SMH <- rnorm(10)
d<- data.table(height.pre.AM,height.pre.EM,height.pre.SMH,height.post.AM,height.post.EM,height.post.SMH)
```

I would then like to calculate 3 new vectors, the change in height between pre and post vectors, by each identifier in the list. I can do this with 3 lines that look like this:

```
d[,delta_EM  := height.post.EM  - height.pre.EM ]
d[,delta_AM  := height.post.AM  - height.pre.AM ]
d[,delta_SMH := height.post.SMH - height.pre.SMH]
```

How can I do this with a single line, and a vector stored as `v.list` is above?

I tried a for loop constructed as:

```
for(i in 1:  length(v.list)){
  v   <- (noquote(paste(v.list[i]))) 
  pre <- paste("d[,delta_",v,":= height.post.",v," - height.pre.",v,"]",sep="")
  cat(noquote(pre), sep="\n")
}
```

However, this just prints the lines, rather than executing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
for (v in v.list)
  d[, paste0('delta_', v) := get(paste0('height.post.', v)) -
                             get(paste0('height.pre.', v))]
```

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is to transform your data into long format first. With the enhanced `melt` function from *data.table* you can use multiple measures by patterns and as a result create more than one value column (in this case a *pre* and a *post* value column):

```
melt(d, measure.vars = patterns("pre","post"), 
     value.name = c("height.pre","height.post"))[, variable := v.list[variable]
                                                 ][, delta_height := height.post - height.pre][]
```

which gives:

```
    variable  height.pre height.post delta_height
 1:       AM  1.51181796  0.20232291   -1.3094951
 2:       AM  0.65902517  0.51772371   -0.1413015
 3:       AM  1.12202807  1.67814321    0.5561151
 4:       AM -0.78464137  0.38524481    1.1698862
 5:       AM -0.42569229 -1.28188722   -0.8561949
 6:       AM  0.39299759 -0.58215074   -0.9751483
 7:       AM  0.03675713  1.77411869    1.7373616
 8:       AM -1.03208366 -0.21067198    0.8214117
 9:       AM -1.26486147 -0.35210691    0.9127546
10:       AM -0.22696529  0.58517233    0.8121376
11:       EM  0.74558930  1.01368470    0.2680954
12:       EM  0.33281918 -0.02256943   -0.3553886
.....
```

Answer (score 3):

There is probably a better way, but here's what I came up with that seems to work.  You could use `lapply()` and `get()` inside the data table.

```
d[, paste0("delta_", v.list) := lapply(v.list, function(x) {
    s <- sort(grep(x, names(d), fixed = TRUE, value = TRUE)) 
    get(s[1]) - get(s[2]) 
})]
```

Alternatively, you could parse and evaluate some expressions.

```
cols <- lapply(v.list, function(x) {
    g <- grep(paste0("p(ost|re)\\.", x), names(d), value = TRUE)
    eval(parse(text = paste(g, collapse = "-")), envir = d)
})

d[, paste0("delta_", v.list) := cols]
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider making use of the [**`dplyr`**](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) and [**`tidyr`**](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/) as those packages lend themselves very well for those kind of operations and generate readable and neat workflow code.

```
Vectorize(require)(package = c("dplyr", "tidyr"),
                   character.only = TRUE)
dComplete <- d %>%
    gather(key = indPre, value = valPre, contains("pre")) %>% 
    gather(key = indPost, value = valPost, contains("post")) %>% 
    mutate(diff = valPost - valPre)
```

## Preview

### Data

I `set.seed(1)` for reproducibility:

#### Original data

```
set.seed1(1)
height.pre.AM   <- rnorm(10)
height.pre.EM   <- rnorm(10)
height.pre.SMH  <- rnorm(10)
height.post.AM  <- rnorm(10)
height.post.EM  <- rnorm(10)
height.post.SMH <- rnorm(10)
d<- data.frame(height.pre.AM, height.pre.EM, height.pre.SMH,
               height.post.AM,height.post.EM,height.post.SMH)
```

### Results preview

```
> head(dComplete)
         indPre     valPre        indPost    valPost       diff
1 height.pre.AM  0.2426995 height.post.AM -1.0155539 -1.2582534
2 height.pre.AM -0.7978763 height.post.AM  0.7602261  1.5581023
3 height.pre.AM -0.2440429 height.post.AM -1.7585200 -1.5144772
4 height.pre.AM -1.4228071 height.post.AM  0.7663306  2.1891377
5 height.pre.AM  1.6237066 height.post.AM  1.0676800 -0.5560266
6 height.pre.AM  0.3561212 height.post.AM -0.4366372 -0.7927584
```

---

If desired, you may later [`spread`](http://rpubs.com/bradleyboehmke/data_wrangling) your values into one column; depends how you want to use this data.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
library(dplyr)

calculate_delta <-function(df, id){
    calc_string <- paste('height.post.', id, ' - height.pre.', id, sep = '')
    vector <- mutate_(df, 'delta' = calc_string)$delta
}


vector_list <- setNames(lapply(v.list, function(x) calculate_delta(d, x)), v.list)
```

You could cram it into one line if you wanted, but that wouldn't be very readable.